# MFC how to get path from MFCEditBrowseControl and copy it to the edit control?

Tags: visual-c++, path, mfc

I am intended to get path from **CMFCEditBrowseControl** and copy it to the CEdit edit box. I have done the following which is getting caption of a dialog not path, please let me know how to get the path using MFC and c++ to save particular file to the destination?

```
CString strTextone;
(CMFCEditBrowseCtrl *) GetDlgItem(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1)-&inFileCtrl;
GetWindowText(strTextone);
(CEdit *) GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2)-&e_Edit;
SetWindowText(strTextone);
```

This is my code. I am beginner to this, so please correct my mistakes!

Comment: Don't ask 2 questions in one. Doing so limits the usefulness of any potential answer to those users, that need the exact combination. I don't know what the real issue is, that you are trying to solve. Nor do I know, why you posted fake code, code that doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a pointer to `CWnd`:

```
CString strTextone;
CWnd* ptr = GetDlgItem(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1);
ptr->GetWindowText(strTextone);
ptr->SetWindowText(_T("something else"));
```

This will work because `SetWindowText/GetWindowText` are `CWnd` methods. You could use `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl*` cast but that's not always safe. The preferred method is to declare a class member:

```
CMFCEditBrowseCtrl mfc_editbrowse;
```

And add subclass in `DoDataExchange`.

```
void CMyDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, mfc_editbrowse);
}
```

Then you can use `m_editbrowse` to access `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` methods.

Comment: Another way: `GetDlgItemText(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, strTextone);`